# Restricting access to communities detail page

Tags: community, website-integration

We have build a public website in salesforce and the urls look something like:

https://ourdomain.force.com/ourdomain/CommunitiesMyProfilesSidebar2?block=ContactInfo
This works perfectly and shows contact information.

https://ourdomain.force.com/ourdomain/ goes also to contact information.
So far everything is OK.

Now if I type https://ourdomain.force.com/ourdomain/anything_here_that_is_not_valid
I go to a standard(ish) salesforce page with a 'Recent Items' box on the left and a Global search bar at the top, etc...
Even worse. If I 'guess' a valid id I can even edit and clone the record in a standard page layout. That is not a big problem because you can only edit/clone your own records but it looks ugly.

Is there any way to prevent this?

I already looked at the man pages for the communities profile and basically looked over everything in the setup. Also google is no help here...

Comment: I've solved part of it. The only problem left is when you know the id of one of your objects you still go to a salesforce screen ie  https://ourdomain.force.com/ourdomain/valid_id_here

Comment: Also  http://ourdomain.force.com/ourdomain/valid_tree_digit_start where valid_three_digit_start is the first 3 digits of a valid id (001 for example) goes to a standard salesforce page.

Comment: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E6tDQAS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce came back to me and they told us it couldn't be done.

- You can not have a custom 404 for users that are logged in.
- You can not restrict access to standard salesforce pages for community users that are logged in. (show a 404 when a user goes to a standard page you don't want them to see)
- You can redirect certain pages (for example /001/e) but if someone adds something to the url (/001/e?blabla) it still goes there; You can not use wildcards

Comment: Can't we use UrlRewriter class to display end-user just a custom pages?

Comment: Cant use UrlRewriter - I tried this today incidentally to try to solve this very problem, and urlRewriter never actually gets called, perhaps because the url is not considered part of the site.

Answer (score 3):

Its a very OLD thread but I faced same issue and after a lot of research I found that there is Salesforce inbuilt configuration for it (Unfortunately no documents for it)

You Can Remove access from All Salesforce Standard Pages for a community/site where we want to host only our VF pages.

- Go To Setup - Site
- Your Site and edit it
- Uncheck "Allow Access to Standard Salesforce Pages"
- Save

[image]