# Preventing Community Users from Seeing Standard SFDC UI

Tags: visualforce, permissions, community

Like others before me, I would like to restrict my community users to only viusalforce pages. Most of the questions regarding this seem a bit dated. Are 
there any new and improved ways to deal with this?

Relevant other questions

- [Showing visualforce pages to Communities users, but standard Salesforce pages to all other users, without writing a dozen controller extensions!](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60249/showing-visualforce-pages-to-communities-users-but-standard-salesforce-pages-to)
- [Restricting access to communities detail page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23947/restricting-access-to-communities-detail-page)
- [Preventing Community Users from Seeing Standard SFDC UI when using Site.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72418/preventing-community-users-from-seeing-standard-sfdc-ui-when-using-site-com)
- [Is there a way to stop an user from seeing an object except when obtained by apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122779/is-there-a-way-to-stop-an-user-from-seeing-an-object-except-when-obtained-by-ape)

These solutions are based on:

- Overwrite all standard page links, and have a controller figure out
  where the community user should go.
- Use javascript to redirect community users away from standard page urls.
- Create new page layouts that minimize what is visible.
- Restrict read access to all fields, and use an apex class with the `without sharing` keyword to make information available as needed.

Comment: What community template are you using?

Comment: Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce. But i really don't want the tabs ;)

Comment: If you use something like Bootstrap you can have all the navigation handled via VF pages with a home page component then the other parts navigated to from that home page and say a sidebar component.

Comment: @DaveHumm Thanks, I did that. Is there an easy way to prevent people from hacking the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have pretty much sum it all.

Here are few additional points:

1. [Brand communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_branding.htm&type=0):

   - Customize look and feel.
   - By placing HTML file in header, customize look and feel as per the requirement.
2. Use [template](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_templates_composition.htm):

   - to reuse header navigation and footer functionalities.
3. Standard pages:

   - Override standard buttons such as view, edit and new record pages, and list views with custom pages if necessary.
   - For custom pages try reusing the functionality as much as possible with use of field sets.

Comment: Thank you for your addition. Too bad nothing has changed ;)